# Office JS getAccessTokenAsync sending wrong auth url

Tags: office365, office-js

Using `getAccessTokenAsync` method of OfficeJS API I am trying to get the access token. However after investigation using developer tools -> network I get the request which is being fired in callback of `getAccessTokenAsync`. When I compare it with working url which were constructed manually I see that some parameters are completely different. For example the ID `bc59ab01-8403-45c6-8796-ac3ef710b3e3` in the first url is wrong and should be `bc59ab01-8403-45c6-8796-ac3ef710b3e3` (this ID is registered in Azure AD and in manifest aswell). Why its generating the url which is getting the ID which is nowhere in my project and in general why its not working?

request generated by `getAccessTokenAsync` (not working)

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=bc59ab01-8403-45c6-8796-ac3ef710b3e3&resource=api%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fc64ded7d-29e6-4083-8afa-351c7a630668&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2Fowa%2FextSSO.aspx&state=5e7fc82d-190f-4817-8159-25caf2b58687%7Capi%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fc64ded7d-29e6-4083-8afa-351c7a630668&client-request-id=32957e85-9ebe-44b9-b8b2-d67ec469f19e&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.15&prompt=none&login_hint=<myEmail>&domain_hint=<domain>
```

Request constructed manually (working)

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<nameOfCompany>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=c64ded7d-29e6-4083-8afa-351c7a630668&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=678910
```

WebApplicationInfo element in manifest.xml

```
<WebApplicationInfo>
    <Id>c64ded7d-29e6-4083-8afa-351c7a630668</Id>
    <Resource>api://localhost:3000/c64ded7d-29e6-4083-8afa-351c7a630668</Resource>
    <Scopes>
        <Scope>files.read.all</Scope>
        <Scope>profile</Scope>
    </Scopes>
 </WebApplicationInfo>
```

Comment: Which version and build of Outlook are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus 16.0.8827.2148

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit too complex to put in a comment, so I'll make an answer for now.

1. Please clarify what you mean by "not working". What error is being returned by `getAccessTokenAsync`?
2. It looks to me like your manual request is getting an access token to MS Graph for the add-in (`c64ded7d-29e6-4083-8afa-351c7a630668`). This is not parallel to what `getAccessTokenAsync` does. `getAccessTokenAsync` gets an access token that gives the *Office host* access **to** your add-in. The Office Online client ID is `bc59ab01-8403-45c6-8796-ac3ef710b3e3`, so it is expected that that is the client ID that Office would use in its request. (Search for that GUID in the article [Create SSO Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-aspnet).) Also, notice that `c64ded7d-29e6-4083-8afa-351c7a630668` is in the value for the "resource" of that request, which is expected because your add-in is the resource to which the Office host needs access.
3. To get access to *Graph*, you need server-side code that swaps the token that you get from `getAccessTokenAsync` for an access token that gives *your add-in* access **to** MS Graph by using the "on behalf of" flow. In that transaction, your add-in is the client and Graph is the resource. For more information, see the article [SSO in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins)